# Open closest Details element onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to have a button that opens the closest details element (above button) without using ID.
I've tried variations of the following code and search every thread but can't figure it out

```js
function openDetail(detailsElement) {
    detailsElement.setAttribute("open");
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Summary 1</summary>
    Test 1
</details>
<button onclick="openDetail(closest)">button</button>
<details>
    <summary>Summary 2</summary>
    Test 2
</details>
<button onclick="openDetail(closest)">button</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.prev()` to get previous element from button .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function openDetail(detailsElement) {
  $(detailsElement).prev().attr('open','open')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary>Summary 1</summary>
  Test 1
</details>
<button onclick="openDetail(this)">button</button>

<details>
  <summary>Summary 2</summary>
  Test 2
</details>
<button onclick="openDetail(this)">button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. is there a way for this to work on a **div** instead of a **button**?

Comment: this will work there as well just change button to div. Let me know if you face any problem by creating jsfiddle  .

Comment: Oh I see my issue was my button was inside another div and it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/ru91Lx6t/

Comment: use `$(detailsElement).parent().prev().attr('open','open')` see if that work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const details = document.querySelectorAll("details");

function openDetail(detailPosition) {
  const pos = details[detailPosition - 1];
  pos.open = !pos.open;
}
    
<details>
<summary>Summary 1</summary>
  Test 1
</details>
<button onclick="openDetail(1)">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `previousElementSibling` property here and then use `setAttribute` for `open` `true`. Please check below code:

```js
function openDetail(e) {
    const closet = e.previousElementSibling;
    closet.setAttribute("open", true);
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Summary 1</summary>
    Test 1
</details>
<button onclick="openDetail(this)">button</button>
<details>
    <summary>Summary 2</summary>
    Test 2
</details>
<button onclick="openDetail(this)">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   
    var id = $(this).attr("target-id");
     console.log(id)
    var key = "#" + id;
     var item = $('' + key + '').attr("open",true)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details id="one">
<summary>Summary 1</summary>
Test 1
</details>
 <button target-id="one">button</button>
 
 <details id="two">
<summary>Summary 2</summary>
Test 2
</details>
 <button target-id="two"  >button</button>
```